# RenderLink returns "Empty String " in Glass.Mapper

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-mvc, glass-mapper

I'm trying to show a title of a news as a link

```
    @using Glass.Mapper.Sc.Web.Mvc
    @model MVC.com.Models.News

   it works:<a href="@Model.Url">@Model.Title</a><br/>
   it dosen't work : @Html.Glass().RenderLink(x => x.Url,new {@class=""} ,true, Model.Title)
```

Anchor tag works fine but can not generate a link using RenderLink.

Meanwhile, is there any way I can eliminate @Html.Glass() helper from lines? I added Glass.Mapper.Sc.Web.Mvc to file Web.config but still have to wirte @Html.Glass() at the beginning of each command

Answer (score 1):

You can eliminate @Html.Glass() this way:

```
@using Glass.Mapper.Sc.Web.Mvc

@RenderLink(Model, x => x.Link, new { @class = "btn" }, true,Model.Title)
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you can do this which should eliminate @Html.Glass()

```
@inherits GlassView<News>
```

after that i think you should be able to do this.

```
@RenderLink(Model, x=>x.Url,new{@class=""},true)
```